# VLC Stream with highest resolution

Tags: windows, windows-10, vlc-media-player

How to set up VLC to play YouTube videos in highest resolution. I have tried "Full HD" and "Best Quality" options but its stuck on 1280 x 720. When I play video on YouTube site video plays in Full HD; 1920 x 1080.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the source?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I suggest using youtube-dl instead. It can also list the formats available. Not all videos are available in all resolutions.

Comment: And how to do that?